# query does all rows correct except for row 9

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

this is the code. whenever i input data it works fine. it counts every row correctly EXCEPT for game #9. every single game is counted correctly but game #9. ive sat through and asked 3 people for help. now im turning to you to help me figure out why this is happening.

this is the code:

```
<?php

include ("../conn_inc.php");
include ("../conn_inc_pdo.php");
require_once ('auth.php');

$game_id= $_POST['game_id'];
$resultat= $_POST['namn'];
$lag1=substr($resultat, 0,1);
$lag2=substr($resultat, 2,1);


if ($lag1>$lag2){
    $tips="1";
}
if ($lag1<$lag2){
    $tips="2";
}
if ($lag1==$lag2){
    $tips="x";
}

//echo $tips;

    //------------------FIND ALL ALREADY POSTED GAMES---------------\\

    $sql2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT game_id FROM vm2014res WHERE :game_id = game_id");
    $sql2->execute(array(':game_id' => $game_id));

    if ($sql2->rowCount() == 0) {

        //------ IRRELEVANT TEST CODE 3 LINES DOWN-----\\
        echo $game_id;
        echo $resultat;
        echo "<br>";


           //----------- INSERT THE VALUE OF THE GAME IF IT DOESNT EXIST -------\\
            $q = "INSERT INTO vm2014res (game_id, resultat, added)  VALUES (:game_id, :resultat, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
            $query = $pdo->prepare($q);
            $query->execute(array(
                ':game_id' => $game_id,
                ':resultat' => $resultat
                ));

                     //------------------CHECK IF YOU SHOULD BE GETTING POINTS FOR A CORRECT GUESSED RESULT---------------\\
            $SQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vm2014 WHERE game_id = :game_id AND resultat = :resultat");
            $SQL->execute(array(':game_id' => $game_id, ':resultat' => $resultat));
            $r = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($r as $row){    


               $bet_id = $row['bet_id'];
               $game_id = $row['game_id'];
               $tips = $row['tips'];
               $resultat = $row['resultat'];
               $namn = $row['namn'];
               $points = $row['points'];

               //-------- ALL ECHOS DOWN HERE ARE IRRELEVANT----------\\
               echo $bet_id;
               echo $game_id;
               echo $tips;
               echo $resultat;
               echo $namn;
               echo $points;
               echo "<br>";
               $points=$points+2;
               echo $points;

    //------------- UPDATE THE POINTS GOTTEN (2 POINTS)---------\\

            $sql2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE vm2014 SET points = :points WHERE bet_id = :bet_id");
            $sql2->execute(array(':points' => $points,
            ':bet_id' => $bet_id
            ));

            }

            //------------------CHECK IF YOU SHOULD BE GETTING POINTS FOR RIGHT GUESSED GAME---------------\\
            $SQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vm2014 WHERE game_id = :game_id AND tips = :tips");
            $SQL->execute(array(':game_id' => $game_id, ':tips' => $tips));
            $r = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($r as $row){    


               $bet_id = $row['bet_id'];
               $game_id = $row['game_id'];
               $tips = $row['tips'];
               $resultat = $row['resultat'];
               $namn = $row['namn'];
               $points = $row['points'];

             //-------IRRELEVANT ECHOS DOWN HERE--------\\
               echo $bet_id;
               echo $game_id;
               echo $tips;
               echo $resultat;
               echo $namn;
               echo $points;
               echo "<br>";
               $points=$points+1;
               echo $points;

    //----------------- UPDATE YOUR POINTS IF YOU SHOULD BE GETTING POINTS FOR THE GAME----\\

            $sql2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE vm2014 SET points = :points WHERE bet_id = :bet_id");
            $sql2->execute(array(':points' => $points,
            ':bet_id' => $bet_id
            ));

            }

    } else {
        //-----------------POST WHEN THE GAME RESULT WAS ADDED TO THE DB-------\\
            $SQL6 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vm2014res WHERE game_id = :game_id");
            $SQL6->execute(array(':game_id' => $game_id));
            $ra = $SQL6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($ra as $row){ 

               $game_id = $row['game_id'];
               $resultat = $row['resultat'];
               $added = $row['added'];

        echo "Resultatet är redan registrerat. Det registrerades: <strong>" . $added . "</strong> och det vart <strong>" . $resultat . "</strong> i matchen.";
            }
    }
```

ive included the entire part of the code because i dont know where the wrong part of the code is. it should be in the part which is followed by:

```
//------------------Kolla om du ska få poäng för ditt tips---------------\\
```

but i cant see the problem.

im inputting 2-1 into game 9. and this is the input to the database: (i dont know how to make a table of this on this website)

```
    bet_id  game_id tips    resultat    name      poäng 
    9           9   1       2-1         Player 1  2 
    57          9   x       1-1         Player 2  0 
    105         9   x       1-1         Player 3  0 
    153         9   1       2-0         Player 4  0 
    201         9   1       2-1         Player 5  2 
    249         9   1       3-0         Player 6  0 
    297         9   x       1-1         Player 7  0 
    345         9   x       0-0         Player 8  0 
    393         9   2       0-1         Player 9  1 
    441         9   1       1-0         Player 10 0 
    489         9   2       0-3         Player 11 1 
    537         9   x       0-0         Player 12 0 
    585         9   x       1-1         Player 13 0 
    633         9   1       2-0         Player 14 0 
    681         9   2       1-2         Player 15 1 
    729         9   2       0-1         Player 16 1 
    777         9   x       1-1         Player 17 0 
    825         9   1       3-0         Player 18 0 
    873         9   2       2-3         Player 19 1 
    921         9   2       0-1         Player 20 1 
    969         9   x       2-2         Player 21 0 
    1017        9   x       2-2         Player 22 0 
    1065        9   2       2-1         Player 23 3 
    1113        9   x       0-0         Player 24 0 
    1161        9   2       1-1         Player 25 1
```

and as you can see, some players are getting points for being wrong. some are getting points for a correct result, but not getting for guessing who won the game.

can someone please help me figuring out whats wrong?

Comment: First you have to explain HOW that sample output shows what's right/wrong. I have NO idea what `2-2` or `2-1` means. and we're not going to read through a wall of basically totally undocumented code to try and guess what the problem is.

Comment: 2-1 is a result. 2 against 1. and i dont know what to add comments to. i can try though

Comment: @MarcB ive added as much comments as possible

Comment: @saknarnamn your parameters seem to be the wrong way around: `$sql2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT game_id FROM vm2014res WHERE :game_id = game_id");` should be `WHERE game_id = :game_id");`

Comment: where is the part where you actually compare wether their guess (tip?) is correct or wrong? I see the comment about checking if they should be getting point, but no actual comparison...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier its in the first part. where its says "lag1" and "lag2". then when i have if the match was a 1, x or 2 i compare it to the database which holds a 1, x or 2

Comment: @user574632 ive changed it to that. sadly it didnt fix my problem. thanks for the help

Comment: @user574632 in fact this doesn't make any change. you can compare values before of after the equal sign, the comparison is considered as a whole

Answer (score 0):

First you calucate `$tips`:

```
if ($lag1>$lag2){
  $tips="1";
}
```

Then, you overwrite it with a database result:

```
//------------------CHECK IF YOU SHOULD BE GETTING POINTS FOR A CORRECT GUESSED RESULT---------------\\
/* ... */
$tips = $row['tips'];
```

One of the variables should have a different name.

Some further problems:

```
$resultat= $_POST['namn'];
```

I'm assuming that `$resultat` is the result of a game, and that `'namn'` is the name of a player. This cannot possibly be correct.

```
$lag1=substr($resultat, 0,1);
$lag2=substr($resultat, 2,1);
```

What if one team scores more than nine goals in a game? You should [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the result with `'-'` as the delimiter.

Comment: actually, namn is not the name of a player in this matter. i was just using an old part of a website i did and didnt bother to fix that part. its the string for the result. and yeah, i should use explode. but for this version substr will work fine because for one to get over 9 goals in one game would be amazing and ive never seen it happened. thanks for your help